# Problema em Função IONIC 2 Typescript - Função executa apenas uma vez

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

Boa Noite!

Estou com uma problema em uma função no Typescript(Ionic 2).
A função faz uma busca/filtro a partir dos conteúdos das tags. O usuário digita o número que deseja buscar e a função filtra a partir do número digitado.
Na primeira vez que a tela de consulta é chamada, a função executa normalmente, sem problema, podendo inclusive fazer diversas buscas.
Porém, ao sair da tela e voltar nela pra realizar mais consultas, a busca já não funciona, não realiza a filtragem.
Alguém pode ajudar a solucionar esse problema?

```
myFunction() {

        this.input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        this.filter = this.input.value.toUpperCase();
        this.ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        this.li = this.ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

        for (this.i = 0; this.i < this.li.length; this.i++) 
        {
          this.a = this.li[this.i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

          if(this.a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.filter)> -1) 
          {
              this.li[this.i].style.display = "";
          } else {
              this.li[this.i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
  }
```

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Recomendo que vc de uma pesquisada em reactive forms e  use o metodo onChanges para filtrar seus elementos. Esse jeito que vc esta fazendo nao e um jeito bom de se fazer com angular parece mais uma solução de jquery/vanilla js

Comment: Eu acredito que o melhor para você seria dar uma lida sobre o NgModel do Angular/Ionic seu código ficaria melhor e além disso ele teria algumas propriedades a mais para te ajudar.

Comment: Legal, agradeço muito as boas dicas! Vou procurar e modificar. Obrigado.